# Featherlight: Loading a iframe using just javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I'm using Featherlight to create a "pop-up" of an iframe, specifically a page with Terms & Conditions that needs to be accepted before the site can be viewed.

Technically it is working...the popup appears and operates just the way it's suppose to. However, there is an error that appears in the console that stops any subsequent scripts from operating:

`TypeError: target is undefined`

I think this is caused by the fact that I'm calling the iframe purely through javascript instead of calling an HTML element like a div.

This is my code (I'm using WordPress which is why there's a `.env('WP_HOME')` in there):

```
<script>
    var iframe = "'.env('WP_HOME').'/terms-conditions/";
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.featherlight(
        iframe, {
            variant: "fl-terms",
            type: "iframe",
            closeOnEsc: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            closeIcon: "",
            otherClose: "#accept-submit",
            beforeClose: function(event){
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think there may be something wrong with the configuration but I haven't been able to figure out what because I haven't found a similar code example yet.

---

**Thanks to imvain2's suggestions, this is my final code that does not cause errors:**

```
<script>
    var iframe = "'.env('WP_HOME').'/terms-conditions/";
    jQuery("#_top").featherlight(
    iframe, {
        variant: "fl-terms",
        type: "iframe",
        closeOnEsc: false,
        closeOnClick: false,
        closeIcon: "",
        otherClose: "#accept-submit",
        beforeClose: function(event){
            return false;
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#_top").click();
    });
</script>
```

**And in my `header.php`, I added the following directly under the `<body>` tag:**

```
<a id="_top" class="no-scroll" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/) FL will bind to what element you pass it unless you disable autobind, but then that looks for the data attribute.

Try binding the function to body (or document).

```js
    var iframe = "'.env('WP_HOME').'/terms-conditions/";
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("body").featherlight(
        iframe, {
            variant: "fl-terms",
            type: "iframe",
            closeOnEsc: false,
            closeOnClick: false,
            closeIcon: "",
            otherClose: "#accept-submit",
            beforeClose: function(event){
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Changing it to `jQuery("body").featherlight` or `jQuery(document).featherlight` gets rid of the error, but now the lightbox doesn't pop up when the page loads. You may be onto something though.

Comment: @Faeldray you could always create an anchor link that opens featherlight then on page load just use jQuery to trigger a click on that element. That way featherlight gets all of the data that it needs.

Comment: That worked! I edited my question to include my final code.